Python for Web Form Filling
When using Python for web scraping, I need a library for filling in web forms, or more specifically, login forms automatically. As I have no additional, complex needs such as parsing JavaScript
The specific needs are:

Exploring/filtering the forms on the website so that I can lock on to the form that I want to fill in.
Fill in the forms.
Submit the forms.
Persist cookies across different webpages so that it would work for e.g. SSO.
Export cookies so that I can do web scraping with other tools.

I am already using BeautifulSoup for other purposes.

I removed mentions of Mechanize and MechanicalSoup, as comparisons are off topic on this site. Hopefully they will pop up as answers though. Thanks!

@NicolasRaoul Thanks, I wasn't aware that comparisons are off topic here. Are there any Stack Exchange sites that I can ask such a question though? Since I really want a comparison between these two libraries.

yes, the other, more appropriate, Stack Exchaneg site is https://www.reddit.com/r/Python/  Seriously, I sometimes get tired of our S.E restrictions, even though I understand why they are in place. As Nicolas corrrectly says, comparissons are off top here, but not there. Sometimes you have to choose the right tool for the job

If you want to simulate user actions (filling out, sending forms, etc.), I suggest you familiarize yourself with Selenium and Playwright.
Two simple examples from the documentation.
Selenium:
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
assert "Python" in driver.title
elem = driver.find_element(By.NAME, "q")
elem.clear()
elem.send_keys("pycon")
elem.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
assert "No results found." not in driver.page_source
driver.close()

Playwright:
from playwright.sync_api import sync_playwright

with sync_playwright() as p:
    browser = p.chromium.launch()
    page = browser.new_page()
    page.goto("http://playwright.dev")
    print(page.title())
    browser.close()

